Forecast of 100 days prices using ARIMA-GARCH model but I encountered error saying the input for garch model is not valid
The below section is the data I take to do the ARIMA-GARCH model.
prices = {72.75, 74.69, 76.28, 76.82, 77.64, 76.6, 75.67, 76.35, 80.04, 80.11,
79.44, 80.23, 81.74, 80.88, 81., 80.28, 82.47, 84.98, 83.91, 84.17, 
84.89, 85.99, 84.79, 84.95, 82.79, 81.63, 81.8, 81.45, 81.35, 78.97, 
78.67, 79.44, 78.97, 77.78, 78.07, 78.45, 79.6, 79.42, 77.38, 77.08, 
76.69, 77.02, 77.82, 78.19, 77.69, 77.53, 77.33, 75.99, 76.34, 75.54, 
74.73, 74.72, 72.76, 72.15, 71.77, 71.35, 70.65, 72.22, 72.82, 73., 
71.97, 72.16, 74.64, 73.61, 73.21, 73.37, 72.42, 74.07, 74.93, 74.31, 
74.5, 74.37, 73.7, 72.91, 73.22, 72.65, 73.06, 71.74, 72.01, 74.92, 
74.34, 74.17, 78.78, 78.25, 77.21, 77.57, 78.14, 77.89, 77.4, 78.55, 
77.79, 77.5, 76.54, 74.74, 74.8, 73.24, 74.46, 75.2, 75.24, 73.06};
arimaModel = TimeSeriesModelFit[TimeSeries[prices], "ARIMA"];
lag = 100;
arimaForecast = TimeSeriesForecast[arimaModel, lag];
residuals = prices - arimaForecast

The above code is fine. It gets no error but from the beginning of the below code error starts.
garchModel = EstimatedProcess[residuals, GARCHProcess[1, 1]]
garchVolatility = 
TimeSeriesForecast[garchModel["ConditionalVariance"], {lag}];
combinedForecast = 
TimeSeriesThread[Plus, {arimaForecast, garchVolatility}];


GARCHProcess takes at lest three arguments of which the second and third must be a list. See the documentation for more details.

i change it in code as you mentioned but did'nt get the forecast in the line finding the garch volatility there is error saying that.
TimeSeriesForecast[
GARCHProcess[1, {0.1}, {0.1}]["ConditionalVariance"], {100}].      TemporalData::invstrct: The data TemporalData[73.3731,Automatic,ValueDimensions->Automatic] is not a structurally valid TemporalData object.    TemporalData::invstrct: The data TemporalData[TimeSeriesForecast[GARCHProcess[1,{0.1},{0.1}][ConditionalVariance],{100}],Automatic,ValueDimensions->Automatic] is not a structurally valid TemporalData object.
